# Array in Java program bizarre behaviour

Tags: java

I came across this Java program and its behaving in unexpected way. The following program computes the differences between pairs of elements in an int array.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SetTest
{
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
            int vals[] = {786,678,567,456,
                          345,234,123,012};

            Set<Integer> diffs = new HashSet<Integer>();

            for(int i=0; i < vals.length ; i++)
                for(int j = i; j < vals.length; j++)
                       diffs.add(vals[i] - vals[j]);

            System.out.print(diffs.size());
       }
}
```

If we analyze it seems set size should be 8 which is the size of the array. But if you ran this program it prints 14. What's going on? Any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Answer: This strange behavior happens because 012 in the array becomes octal if we change it to 12 then it prints 8 as expected.

Lesson: Never pad an integer literal with zeros.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you noticed that [012](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) (octal) is 10 (decimal) ?

Comment: +1 as this was actual issue according to edited question.

Answer (score 3):

> If we analyze it seems set size should
>   be 8 which is the size of the array.
>   But if you ran this program it prints
>   14. What's going on? Any idea?

Just trace info

```
1   : 786 - 786 = 0 (new one 1 )
2   : 786 - 678 = 108   (new one 2 )
3   : 786 - 567 = 219   (new one 3 )
4   : 786 - 456 = 330   (new one 4 )
5   : 786 - 345 = 441   (new one 5 )
6   : 786 - 234 = 552   (new one 6 )
7   : 786 - 123 = 663   (new one 7 )
8   : 786 - 10 = 776    (new one 8 )
9   : 678 - 678 = 0 (already contained)
10  : 678 - 567 = 111   (new one 9 )
11  : 678 - 456 = 222   (new one 10 )
12  : 678 - 345 = 333   (new one 11 )
13  : 678 - 234 = 444   (new one 12 )
14  : 678 - 123 = 555   (new one 13 )
15  : 678 - 10 = 668    (new one 14 )
16  : 567 - 567 = 0 (already contained)
17  : 567 - 456 = 111   (already contained)
18  : 567 - 345 = 222   (already contained)
19  : 567 - 234 = 333   (already contained)
20  : 567 - 123 = 444   (already contained)
21  : 567 - 10 = 557    (new one 15 )
22  : 456 - 456 = 0 (already contained)
23  : 456 - 345 = 111   (already contained)
24  : 456 - 234 = 222   (already contained)
25  : 456 - 123 = 333   (already contained)
26  : 456 - 10 = 446    (new one 16 )
27  : 345 - 345 = 0 (already contained)
28  : 345 - 234 = 111   (already contained)
29  : 345 - 123 = 222   (already contained)
30  : 345 - 10 = 335    (new one 17 )
31  : 234 - 234 = 0 (already contained)
32  : 234 - 123 = 111   (already contained)
33  : 234 - 10 = 224    (new one 18 )
34  : 123 - 123 = 0 (already contained)
35  : 123 - 10 = 113    (new one 19 )
36  : 10 - 10 = 0   (already contained)
```

Also, debugger is a great thing in cases when you can't analyze program's behavior ;)

Comment: Could you go into a bit more detail I'm still a little confused about whats going on here?

Comment: @Grammin, glad to help. I've added even more trace info to answer)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are running two nested loops the `add()` method is called multiple times. Since a set cannot contain duplicate objects the number of values in the set will be the number of unique values. The `add()` function returns true if the set did not already contain the element and false if the set already had the element.

Change the line

```
diffs.add(vals[i] - vals[j]);
```

to

```
System.out.println((diffs.add(vals[i] - vals[j])));
```

to see what I mean.

Comment: +1 for being the only one to cover the fact that a Set allows each value only once && that the loops are nested.

Answer (score -1):

For a set of 8 elements, there are 36 (8 + 7 + ... + 1) distinct pairs (if one ignores the order of elements in the pairs). So `diffs` may contain *up to* 36 elements. But apparently, some differences occur multiple times, e.g. 456-345 = 111 and 345-234 = 111. As a set can only contain each value at most once, only the 14 *distinct* differences remain.

Answer (score -1):

Your HashSet only stores non-duplicated values.  If you want duplicates, you have to use a different set type.  The size of diffs should be 36 with duplicates; I get a size of 19 when I run the code as-is (19 unique different values).

Answer (score -1):

It actually prints out 19 here...

You have 36 calculations out of which 17 have an identical result. The HashSet only keeps unique values, this is why we don't have a size of 36 but a size of 19 ...